# Java BufferedReader.readLine() Skipped One Line

Tags: java, user-input, bufferedreader, readline

I'm trying to make some distributed java RMI program, where I encountered a problem when I need to take input from the user. In the following code snippet, entering `1` seems to be good, but entering `2` first time cause nothing to print, when I entered `2` again, then it worked.

How did that happened? Checked the `BufferedReader.readLine()` function documentation but didn't find anything relate to this. Does this have anything to do with `else if`?

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {

    private static BufferedReader lineOfText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public test() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        System.out.println("1 to create an auction, 2 to close an auction");
        if (Integer.parseInt(lineOfText.readLine()) == 1) {
            System.out.println("1 recieved");
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(lineOfText.readLine()) == 2) {
            System.out.println("2 recieved");
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        test t = new test();
    }
}
```

input `1`:

```
1 to create an auction, 2 to close an auction
1 //<- that's the input
1 recieved
```

input `2`:

```
1 to create an auction, 2 to close an auction
2 //<- that's the input yet nothing happened
2 //<- input again
2 recieved
```

Also tried the code snippet on some online compiler and the result is the same as my VSCode. This might be a simply problem but I don't know what happened ;\

Comment: `if (readline == 1) { ... } else if (readline == 2) {...}`, the problem is, your first `if` statement is stopping to read the input from the buffer and `2` does not match `1` so it drops to the `else if` which waits for input from both again.  Do single readline and then check the results.  I'd also consider using `Scanner` for simplicity

Comment: Yes, I've found the problem. Was using ```Scanner``` before but messed up a little, so tried some ```BufferedReader``` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling "readline()" in both your "if" and "else-if", it will call readline() twice each time it tries to check for the condition: once when it runs the "if" condition, then a second time when running the else-if. When you place a function in the conditional statement like:

```
if(myFunction() == true){}
```

it will ALWAYS run that function before comparing its return value to the condition. So when you have:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(lineOfText.readLine()) == 1) {
        System.out.println("1 recieved");
    } else if (Integer.parseInt(lineOfText.readLine()) == 2) {
        System.out.println("2 recieved");
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

It will call readLine() both when it checks the "if", and again at the "else-if".

You should call readline BEFORE you begin checking it against conditions to ensure it is only ran once:

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {

private static BufferedReader lineOfText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public test() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    
    System.out.println("1 to create an auction, 2 to close an auction");
    String myLine = lineOfText.readLine(); //call readLine() before checking conditions so it only runs once
    if (Integer.parseInt(myLine) == 1) {
        System.out.println("1 recieved");
    } else if (Integer.parseInt(myLine) == 2) {
        System.out.println("2 recieved");
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    test t = new test();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you input `2`, the first if statement read the number and it doesn't equal to `1` of course, then the next if statement won't provide you the last input `2`

You need to put the`readLine()` outside the if to make it only read once.

```
public class test {

    private static BufferedReader lineOfText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public test() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        System.out.println("1 to create an auction, 2 to close an auction");
        
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(lineOfText.readLine());
        
        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("1 recieved");
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("2 recieved");
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        test t = new test();
    }
}
```